# Please improve, don’t delete

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I got a brief but helpful [answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/32857/6556) to my question about [how to get growly sounds out of a bass guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26988/how-to-make-a-bass-growl?noredirect=1#comment47693_26988):

> Sansamp VT pedal will emulate an overdriven tube amp and give you the growl.

This is actually one of the things I tried in my own tone chasing, and it’s good advice! I left a comment about the settings I used with that equipment that worked well for me.

The answer was then deleted and converted to a comment, which I don’t understand. The answer *is* an answer to my question, and a helpful answer too, just a bit too brief, so why was it deleted instead of improving it? Especially since there was a comment on the answer that showed exactly how it could be improved.

Comment: I'm guessing Dr Mayhem removed it because it offered no explanation and is essentially a product recommendation.  Personally I think it does function better as a helpful comment, though I might have taken a pass on removing it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this one because of the flags on it. After I had a quick look at it I agreed with the flags and moved this one to a comment because it really doesn't answer the question from the perspective of any future visitor. It was effectively giving an answer to "How to get this sound" by saying "use this black box", whereas the other posts went into detail on what factors are important in order to create that sound.